# the bootstrap server information will be update while adding new Kaa node to cluster?

Tags: kaa

I am trying to setup a Kaa cluster with 3 kaa-node servers.
The bootstrap server information will be set in sdk while generating sdk.
And endpoint will connect to bootstrap server by it and get operation server information.
If an endpoint is connecting to Kaa-server and the 4th Kaa-node server be added into the Kaa cluster, the endpoint's bootstrap server information and operation server information will be update immediately??
Or we need to generate new sdk to get the newest bootstrap server information??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate new SDK to update the list of bootstrap servers if you add a new one. Usually, you add a new Kaa node configured solely as operation server to scale your performance. The existed bootstrap servers will take care of looking up ones for processing requests from EPs.
How to configure Kaa node only as operation server, see - [system configuration](https://web.archive.org/web/20161026123318/http://kaaproject.github.io:80/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Administration-guide/System-Configuration/)

Comment: Just set the "control_service_enabled" as true and the "bootstrap_service_enabled" & "operations_service_enabled" as false will let the new node only as operation server, right?? If the new node is just as operation server, we can use the original sdk and don't need to generate new sdk?? If we set domain name as bootstrap's host, we also don't need to generate new sdk??

Comment: Yes, yes,  domain name can't affect ip address of bootstrap server, there is definitely no need to generate new SDK.